# Matlab How to use a custom transfer function in neural net training

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm using Matlab2008. There is file template_transfer.m and rename it : fungsiku.m. I write down my function in this file and put it in my working directory. I modified purelin transfer function.
I trained my NN and  I got the outputs. But I got some messages like this

Exception in thread " AWT-EventQue...."
at javax. swing..
at java.awt...

what's wrong with my transfer function?
here is my transfer function 'fungsiku'

```
function out1 = fungsiku(in1,in2,in3,in4)
fn = mfilename;
boiler_transfer

 function n = name
    n = 'fungsiku';

 function r = output_range(fp)
    r = [-6 +5];

 function r = active_input_range(fp)
    r = [-10 +10];

 function fp = param_defaults
   fp = struct;

 function names = param_names
   names = {};

 function err = param_check(fp)  
    err = '';

 function a = apply_transfer(n,fp)
    a = 1.32*n + 0.73;

 function da_dn = derivative(n,a,fp)
     da_dn = 1.32*ones(size(n));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if things work the same way in Matlab 2008, but in newer versions you can try setting your transfer function for a layer directly in neural network object properties:
`net = <network creation code>; net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'fungsiku';` This should set `fungsiku` transfer function for first layer.